# problem with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

When I type set this example, I get

> I, love, my , country

as four different nodes.

I know I am not able to get a syntax for enclosing MULTIPLE words together for tikz-qtree. I tried to look into various examples in manual, but manual has used single words only to exemplify.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
    -- +(0,-8pt)
    -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
    \Tree [.S [.I love my country [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
    [.VP [.V sat ]
    [.PP [.P on ]
    [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer. Just enclose in{}. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
    -- +(0,-8pt)
    -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
    \Tree [.S [.{I love my country}  [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
    [.VP [.V sat ]
    [.PP [.P on ]
    [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Just to high light the change-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
    -- +(0,-8pt)
    -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
    \Tree [.S [.{\colorbox{red}{I love my country}}  [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
    [.VP [.V sat ]
    [.PP [.P on ]
    [.NP [.Det the ] [.N mat ] ] ] ] ]
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```